# Are updated fields processed sequentially in an SQL Statement

Tags: sql, database

If I wanted to move data from one field into another field within the same record and then remove the data from the existing field can this reliably be done in one SQL statement, and is this dependent on the Database Provider?

An example of the SQL I am thinking about is below

```
UPDATE table SET field2 = field1, field1 = '' WHERE keyField = 1
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is reliable because major DB's like Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc. are transactional, which ensure ACID. In other words, it's an all-or-nothing scenario, all changes happen or non happen (if a transaction is rolled-back for example).

However it is not sequential; i.e. doing this would yield the same result:

```
UPDATE table SET field1 = '', field2 = field1 WHERE keyField = 1
```

Rather, your SQL is doing something like this:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field2_NewValue = field1_OriginalValue
,   field1_NewValue = ''
WHERE keyField = 1
```

Comment: By that token i guess it does not matter in which order the update section items are put?